# PHP - Captcha images are not showing on localhost (mac os x)

Tags: php, macos, localhost, captcha

I have tried almost or perhaps all captcha scripts around but got none of them to work locally. The images aren't showing. From the research here, it is mentioned the issue is a module named "GD" is not installed/enabled. However I think it is installed and enabled;

[image: GD]

The current script I'm trying is [Simple PHP math captcha image](http://www.php-help.ro/?s=captcha). I have tried [Secureimage](https://www.phpcaptcha.org/) and few others but same outcome. Error reporting does not show any errors.

System details: Mac Osx Yosemite, PHP version: 5.5.24.

*Note - I haven't tried it on any servers*.

Comment: What about server error logs? If you view the captcha image directly, or better, download it with curl or something similar, what is the output of the script which should be the binary content of the image?

Comment: Problem solved by upgrading PHP @drew010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by upgrading to the new version of PHP: Version 5.6.11. Run this command through terminal and restart apache.

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

---

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

[More details on installation is here](http://php-osx.liip.ch/)